# Ubuntu 14.04 w/ Unity - java application gui does not show

Tags: 14.04, unity, java, gui

When I open certain java-powered applications, the primary GUI will not show up. However, the GUI windows for misc functions such as the "Tips and Tricks" type windows, project creation, save dialog boxes (shown when I use right click the program icon and close the application), etc will appear properly.

I initially saw these symptoms whilst attempting to use the program "yEd" and dismissed it as an issue with yEd itself and Ubuntu compatibility. However, I attempted to install and run "projectlibre" using the .deb package from its sourceforge page, and it also is having the same issues.

Here is some rudimentary diagnostic information that I have gathered regarding the issue:

- The issue is present within the Unity interface
- The applications work fine within xfce on the same distro (Ubuntu 14.04)
- XMind (another java-based application) works fine when installed from .deb
- The following programs are known to have this issue:

  - yEd
  - ProjectLibre
- The following java versions have been tested without success:

  ```
  mgodby@mgodby-nb1:~$ update-java-alternatives -l
  java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
  java-7-oracle 1072 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
  ```

All of this tells me that the problem most likely lies in the way that Unity abstracts java application GUIs, but I cannot figure out what is wrong and why xmind works while yEd and ProjectLibre fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has been solved for you already, but I just ran into the same problem (Ubuntu 14.04, yEd & Unity). I have no idea what causes the problem, but the following workaround worked for me:

- Select the running yEd using the icon in Unity's sidebar.
- Hit Alt+Space. This should show the window menu, but for me it came up empty.
- Hit the up or down arrow key. This should show the menu items.
- Select Maximize.

This way I was able to bring up the yEd window, after that it worked for me.